# How to use jQuery Mobile to create iPhone Web Apps?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been assigned to create a web app for the iPhone, and I was supposed to try jQuery Mobile for developing as it supports many platforms.

- Is PHP a requirement for creating iPhone web apps?
- What other ways can we create an effective web app similar to native apps?

Comment: please refer [this link](http://building-iphone-apps.labs.oreilly.com/) . might get you some ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is not a requirement.  I'm currently using [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) + [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) to create a "native" app.  Effectively it is a browser or webview embedded in a thin native app shell.

If you want true native UI elements then you can also try out [Titanium Appcelerator](http://developer.appcelerator.com/).

Personally I found Appcelerator to be a bit slower to develop in.  Everytime I changed a UI element I would have to wait 30 seconds to deploy it to the emulator and see if it worked.  With jQuery Mobile & PhoneGap I can do a lot of my UI work from a browser.

Comment: Thanks but when considering database like activities which i should rely on? Is it possible to acheive same functionalities as Native Iphone apps? Thank u once again,

Comment: I've never done native iphone development, but both PhoneGap & Titanium offer database support.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not a requirement for creating iPhone web apps. You should be able to use whatever back end programming language you like. jQuery should work without needing a specific server side technology, as it executes on the client side.